# Select Nodes with specific attribute using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want my Linq statement to fetch only customfield with **name="Required"** in the below example

```
   <root>
    <appinfo>
        <application app_id=1234 app_name="SomeName">
        <customfield name="Required" value="123" />
        <customfield name="Not Required" value="234" />
        <customfield name="Not Required" value="345" />
        <customfield name="Not Required" value="456" />
        <customfield name="Not Required" value="678" />
        </application>
    </appinfo>
    ...
    </root>
```

**1234,SomeName,123** needs to be picked in this case

Below is the statement I tried. The commented Where does not work

```
 var appAI =
        from appinfo in doc.Root.Elements()

        let application = appinfo.Elements().First()
        let custom_field = application.Descendants()

        //.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Required" && (string)x.Attribute("value").Value !="" )
        select new
        {
            app_id = (string)application.Attribute("app_id"),
            app_name = (string)application.Attribute("app_name"),
            app_AI = custom_field

        };
```

Comment: Shouldn't `x.Attribute("name") == "Required"` be `x.Attribute("name").Value == "Required"`?

Comment: I tried both. No luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this will work. Note that you can chain "Elements" and some of the other extension methods directly off of `IEnumerable<T>` to make it a bit simpler.

```
from app in doc.Elements("appinfo").Elements("application")
from cf in app.Elements("customfield")
where (string)cf.Attribute("name") == "Required"
select new
{
    app_id = (string)app.Attribute("app_id"),
    app_name = (string)app.Attribute("app_name"),
    app_AI = (string)cf.Attribute("value")
};
```

`Descendants` is very rarely a useful method because it can hide potential structural issues in your document. I wouldn't use it unless I was performing validation elsewhere (like with a XSD).

Comment: It worked .. with a minor change. . For my new XML, it has to be doc.Root.Elements . Also , cf.Attribute("value").Value != "" condition was added

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
var results = 
    from appInfo in d.Elements()
    let application = appInfo.Elements().First()
    let custom_field = application.Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Required" && x.Attribute("value").Value != "")
        .SingleOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        app_id = application.Attribute("app_id").Value,
        app_name = application.Attribute("app_name").Value,
        app_AI = custom_field.Attribute("value").Value
    };
```

I think your main problem was looking at `d.Root.Elements` instead of just `d.Elements`.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVM1qz

Comment: I had missed a root tag in my question. apologies.. I tried with d.Root.Elements(). I get the Object reference not set error

Comment: strange.. When I try on your fiddle link.. Even after adding root, it works fine

Comment: I have found the error . It is because , few nodes do not have a closing tag for application. Have replicated the same here https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUoL4N